# Correct way to recursively create a data.frame from a tree

Tags: r, recursion, tree

I would like to create a flat `data.frame` from a tree in R.

The tree is represented by a list which each contains a key called `children` which contains more lists with more children.

```
tree <-
  list(name="root",
       parent_name='None',
       children=list(
         list(parent_name="root", name="child1", children=list()),
         list(parent_name="root", name="child2", children=list(list(parent_name="child2", name="child3", children=c())))
       )
      )
```

I would like to "flatten" this down into a `data.frame` with the following structure:

```
    name parent_name
1   root        None
2 child1        root
3 child2        root
4 child3      child2
```

I can accomplish this using the following recursive function:

```
walk_tree <- function(node) {
  results <<- rbind(
    results,
    data.frame(
      name=node$name,
      parent_name=node$parent_name,
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE
    )
  )

  for (node in node$children) {
    walk_tree(node)
  }
}
```

This function works fine but requires me to declare a `results` `data.frame` outside of the function:

```
results <- NULL
walk_tree(tree)
results # now contains the data.frame as desired
```

Furthermore, the use of the `<<-` operator causes the following warning to occur when the `walk_tree` function is included as a function in a package:

```
Note: no visible binding for '<<-' assignment to 'results'
```

Using the `<-` operator doesn't (`results` evaluates to `NULL` after running `walk_tree`).

What is the correct way to recursively build a `data.frame` from a tree in R?

Comment: @RonakShah yeah that worked! Care to post an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @RonakShah actually, I'm curious if this will hit a limit with deeply nested trees. I'm going to write a few more tests first.

Comment: Should be fine irrespective of the deepness of the tree as far as they follow the naming convention ("name" and "parent_name").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not far :), using `dplyr::bind_rows`

```
walk_tree <- function(node) {
  dplyr::bind_rows(
    data.frame(
      name=node$name,
      parent_name=node$parent_name,
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE),
    lapply(node$children,walk_tree)
  )
}

walk_tree(tree)

    name parent_name
1   root        None
2 child1        root
3 child2        root
4 child3      child2
```

and the base R version :

```
walk_tree <- function(node) {
  do.call(
    rbind,
    c(
    list(data.frame(
      name=node$name,
      parent_name=node$parent_name,
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)),
    lapply(node$children,walk_tree)
  ))
}

walk_tree(tree)
```

Comment: I double checked and it runs fine for me. I don't really know how to debug this... Anybody else has the issue ?

Comment: If you have above mentionned issue please drop a comment before downvoting, I can't just blind fix it.

Comment: I'm making this as the correct answer because it's the easiest to understand and comes with a base R solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way is to gather all the nodes with "names" and "parent_name" together and make a dataframe with them.

```
#Flatten the nested structure
u_tree <- unlist(tree)

#Gather all the indices where name of the node is equal to parent_name
inds <- grepl("parent_name$", names(u_tree))

#Add them in a dataframe
data.frame(name = u_tree[!inds], parent_name = u_tree[inds])

#    name parent_name
#    root        None
#2 child1        root
#3 child2        root
#4 child3      child2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rev(data.frame(matrix(stack(tree)[,1],,2,T)))#MHHH seems too easy for the task
      X2     X1
1   None   root
2 child1   root
3 child2   root
4 child3 child2

stack(tree)%>%
mutate(new=rep(1:(n()/2),each=2),ind=rep(ind[2:1],n()/2))%>%
spread(ind,values)
  new   name parent_name
1   1   None        root
2   2 child1        root
3   3 child2        root
4   4 child3      child2
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the excellent tree structure from the `ape` package and write your data in parenthetic format (were commas (`,`) represent a vertex and brackets represent edges and your leaves are the "children" - the tree is ended by a semi-colon (`;`)).

```
## Reading a tree
my_tree <- "(child1, (child2, child3));"
tree <- ape::read.tree(text = my_tree)

## Getting the edge table (your flatten format)
tree$edge
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4    1
#[2,]    4    5
#[3,]    5    2
#[4,]    5    3
```

Where `4` is your `root` (the deepest vertex in the tree (number of leaves + 1)). It connects `"child1"` to the vertex `5`. `5` denotes the first vertex linking `"child2"` and `"child3"`.
You can visualise this structure as follow (S3 plot methods for `phylo`)

```
## Plotting the tree
plot(tree)
ape::nodelabels()
```

You can add extra structures (trees) to any child as follows:

```
child1_children <- ape::read.tree(text = "(child4, (child5, child6));")
## Adding child1_children to the first leave
tree2 <- ape::bind.tree(tree, child1_children, where = 1)
## Plotting the tree
plot(tree2)
ape::nodelabels()
tree2$edge
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    6    7
#[2,]    7    3
#[3,]    7    8
#[4,]    8    4
#[5,]    8    5
#[6,]    6    9
#[7,]    9    1
#[8,]    9    2
```

Or remove some using the same principle with `ape::drop.tip`.

Comment: I'm cURLing the tree data from an API so I can't simply re-write the format.